# How can I retrieve SQL field names of a temp table using Perl?

Tags: sql, perl, field

Below is the code I'm using to run the query, parse the result set, and parse the rows (respectively)

```
$exec_ret = $DBS->SQLExecSQL($STMT);

while ($DBS->SQLFetch() == *PLibdata::RET_OK)
{
      $rowfetch = $DBS->{Row}->GetCharValue($colname[$i]);
}
```

Can I grab the column/field name of a temp table using similar syntax?  `$colname[$i]` is predefined at the top to hold the column/field names.  This is hard-coded right now, but I would rather automate it by pushing values into `$colname` inside of a loop that runs before the rows are parsed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What module are you using for database access?  I don't recognize the method names.

If you're using [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI), you can get the column names from the statement handle after executing it:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($STMT);
$sth->execute;
my $columns = $sth->{NAME_uc};

while (my $row = $sth->fetch) {
  for my $i (0 .. $#$row) {
    print "$columns->[$i]: $row->[$i]\n";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

There are 3 versions of the column names: `NAME` gives the column names as the database returns them, `NAME_lc` converts them to all lower case, and `NAME_uc` converts them to all upper case.  If you care about database independence, I suggest you avoid `NAME` and use one of the other two.

Comment: this works, just wish i had it with the other module - i think its one thats innate to informix, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try running **SHOW TABLE yourtable** and treating it as if it were a SELECT.

Comment: yeah, im on informix - show columns for TABLE shows the cols, i'll try that, thanks for the starting point though, it makes sense